# Django REST Framework update date Created

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I have a blog app that is connected to a Django REST Framework API. I am able to create, delete, and update posts using API calls but I'm struggling with updating the time created field. What I want to do is to update the time with the current time when the post is edited. So if the post was created 21 July 2020 at 10 PM, and then it was edited 21 July 2020 10:05 PM I want the time to change according to the time it was edited. Any ideas on how I can do that. I'm using this a fetch call to make the updates.

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogs/";
            var type = "POST";

            if (active != null) {
                url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogs/${active.id}/`;
                type = "PUT";
            }

            fetch(url, {
                method: type,
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                    "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'title': form.title.value,
                    'body': form.body.value,
                    'user': user,
                })
            }).then(function (response) {
                handlePosts()
                location.reload()
                form.reset()
            })

        })
```

I've tried sending new Date() inn the body but it doesn't seem to work.
This is my models.py if i add the save method bellow in the comments:

```
class BlogModel(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        UserModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + ", " + str(self.title)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.created = timezone.now()
       return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My initial thought was that I needed to override the save method of the viewset still working on that...
Any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

```
class BlogModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        UserModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + ", " + str(self.title)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
           self.created = timezone.now()

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Try this code and it will work since you are trying a PUT request

Answer (score 0):

To update the created time field, you can override the `save()` method of your posts model to save that time. You'll not need to send this from your frontend.  For example:

```
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
   ...
   fields
   ...
   

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.time_created_field = timezone.now()
       return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It sounds good, but when i implement that save method, it doesnt save at all

Comment: @adamkb96 please add the model and the save method to your question